# How can I communicate a parameter value from a gitlab CI/CD pipeline via Terraform to a user_data script in AWS?

Tags: gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci

I have defined a terraform configuration that sets up an EC2 instance. I use `user_data` to upload and run a script, which needs a parameter string of some sort - it could be as an environment variable, a small file or whatever. I have put this into gitlab and set up a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file to define a pipeline with a manual stage, and I defined a variable in gitlab's `settings -> CI/CD`; this should make the manual step stop and ask me to specify a value for the variable. I know that if I prefix the name of the variable with `TF_VAR_`, then it will be visible to my terraform scripts.

So, my question is this: I want to use the value in my `user_data` - is this possible?

Comment: It would help if you could show your Terraform code and ideally .gitlab-ci.yml file. If you can do this as a [mcve] then that would be great too and strip out anything unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, I realised, is template files: You specify a variable, eg. `TF_VAR_BACKUP`, in gitlab, under 'Settings' -> 'CI/CD' -> 'Variables'. In the terraform script it is visible like this:

```
variable "BACKUP" {}
...
resource "aws_instance" "bastion" {
  ami = "${var.image}"
  ...
  user_data = "${templatefile("${path.module}/bootstrap.tmpl",{BACKUP = ${var.BACKUP}})}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to implement something similar as the above, but much much simpler. In my Terraform configuration (either in my main.tf or variables.tf file), I'm looking to call a very simple GitLab variable like a Password or connection string, nothing as complex as your resource block depicted above, which has unfortunately got me a bit lost. Are you able to illustrate with a simple example as I've described? Much appreciated.